# Why page get empty when i refresh it in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working with Jquery Mobile.I get the result from JSON file and display it on the page.Content is display through a click event.But When i refresh the page page get empty.What is the Issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your code ??

Comment: https://gist.github.com/taleeb35/fe5d5f81068f0b671d4e

Comment: What will be your default id value ?

Comment: I have 2 pages first page id is "page"  and second one has "page2"

Comment: Yes i can . but you have oreder your code properly. you code is messy . You didn't load data onPageLoad or something. You load data only click on <a> tag.

Comment: I am loading the data on <a> tag click.

Comment: but what do you mean by refresh the page ??

Comment: First time when i click the link data loaded to page then if i press F5 page get empty

Comment: You are on page1 . are redirecting to page2 via click on <a> tag and on refresh you wanna to see data of page2. Am i rigth ??

Comment: If you look the code clearly i used page id to go from 1 page to another

Comment: I click the link from page 1 and call the other page with second page id

Comment: Is my question is not clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i get it: so you are dynamically loading elements on a page but when you refresh everything reverts..... by the look at the approach you have so far this is as expected.

With Jquery mobile you don't use click to dynamically insert elemenets try binding "pagebeforechange" on the whole document and then handle the URL instead.

```
$(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {....})
```

Here is an example for what you are trying to do note Jquery Mobile 1.0 ..(whole source Code pasted below): http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/pages/dynamic-samples/sample-reuse-page.html

Also may want to look at using a newer version of Jquery Mobile.... some of this stuff here may have been deprecated.

**Explanation:**

So basically the "**pagebeforeshow**" handler will fire just before the page appears.

- Write functions to read and handle the URL request
- Call a relevant function that build's the requested page elements

Also you may want to be more descriptive with your link anchor "a href="#""

But why have javascript handle the first landing page at all? Unless you plan on having and obscene amount of data on the first page .....

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>changePage JSON Sample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

// Some sample categorized data. This data is in-memory
// for demonstration purposes, but could be loaded dynamically
// via ajax.
var categoryData = {
 animals: {
  name: "Animals",
  description: "All your favorites from aardvarks to zebras.",
  items: [
   {
    name: "Pets",
   },
   {
    name: "Farm Animals",
   },
   {
    name: "Wild Animals",
   }
  ]
 },
 colors: {
  name: "Colors",
  description: "Fresh colors from the magic rainbow.",
  items: [
   {
    name: "Blue",
   },
   {
    name: "Green",
   },
   {
    name: "Orange",
   },
   {
    name: "Purple",
   },
   {
    name: "Red",
   },
   {
    name: "Yellow",
   },
   {
    name: "Violet",
   }
  ]
 },
 vehicles: {
  name: "Vehicles",
  description: "Everything from cars to planes.",
  items: [
   {
    name: "Cars",
   },
   {
    name: "Planes",
   },
   {
    name: "Construction",
   }
  ]
 }
};

// Load the data for a specific category, based on
// the URL passed in. Generate markup for the items in the
// category, inject it into an embedded page, and then make
// that page the current active page.
function showCategory( urlObj, options )
{
 var categoryName = urlObj.hash.replace( /.*category=/, "" ),

  // Get the object that represents the category we
  // are interested in. Note, that at this point we could
  // instead fire off an ajax request to fetch the data, but
  // for the purposes of this sample, it's already in memory.
  category = categoryData[ categoryName ],

  // The pages we use to display our content are already in
  // the DOM. The id of the page we are going to write our
  // content into is specified in the hash before the '?'.
  pageSelector = urlObj.hash.replace( /\?.*$/, "" );

 if ( category ) {
  // Get the page we are going to dump our content into.
  var $page = $( pageSelector ),

   // Get the header for the page.
   $header = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=header)" ),

   // Get the content area element for the page.
   $content = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=content)" ),

   // The markup we are going to inject into the content
   // area of the page.
   markup = "<p>" + category.description + "</p><ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true'>",

   // The array of items for this category.
   cItems = category.items,

   // The number of items in the category.
   numItems = cItems.length;

  // Generate a list item for each item in the category
  // and add it to our markup.
  for ( var i = 0; i < numItems; i++ ) {
   markup += "<li>" + cItems[i].name + "</li>";
  }
  markup += "</ul>";

  // Find the h1 element in our header and inject the name of
  // the category into it.
  $header.find( "h1" ).html( category.name );

  // Inject the category items markup into the content element.
  $content.html( markup );

  // Pages are lazily enhanced. We call page() on the page
  // element to make sure it is always enhanced before we
  // attempt to enhance the listview markup we just injected.
  // Subsequent calls to page() are ignored since a page/widget
  // can only be enhanced once.
  $page.page();

  // Enhance the listview we just injected.
  $content.find( ":jqmData(role=listview)" ).listview();

  // We don't want the data-url of the page we just modified
  // to be the url that shows up in the browser's location field,
  // so set the dataUrl option to the URL for the category
  // we just loaded.
  options.dataUrl = urlObj.href;

  // Now call changePage() and tell it to switch to
  // the page we just modified.
  $.mobile.changePage( $page, options );
 }
}

 
// Listen for any attempts to call changePage().
$(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
 // We only want to handle changePage() calls where the caller is
 // asking us to load a page by URL.
 if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) {
  // We are being asked to load a page by URL, but we only
  // want to handle URLs that request the data for a specific
  // category.
  var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl( data.toPage ),
   re = /^#category-item/;
  if ( u.hash.search(re) !== -1 ) {
   // We're being asked to display the items for a specific category.
   // Call our internal method that builds the content for the category
   // on the fly based on our in-memory category data structure.
   showCategory( u, data.options );

   // Make sure to tell changePage() we've handled this call so it doesn't
   // have to do anything.
   e.preventDefault();
  }
 }
});


</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="home" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header"><h1>Categories</h1></div>
  <div data-role="content">
   <h2>Select a Category Below:</h2>
   <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
     <li><a href="#category-items?category=animals">Animals</a></li>
     <li><a href="#category-items?category=colors">Colors</a></li>
     <li><a href="#category-items?category=vehicles">Vehicles</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="category-items" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header"><h1></h1></div>
  <div data-role="content"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```